# Не могу создать рандомайзер для дискорд бота

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я Новичок в python и решил сделать бота для своего дс сервера.
Итак, нужно чтобы по команде randomize бот писал в канал: "введите переменные" и затем ждал ответа от пользователя. Затем считывал текст сообщения по строкам и из этих переменных выбирал одну и отправлял в чат.
(за коги не шарю)

вот код: `

```js
import os
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

PREFIX = "-"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.remove_command('help')

# cogs loader
@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 360406449685266432:
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("cogs is loaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("ты же не разработчик")

# cogs unloader
@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 360406449685266432:
        client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("cogs is unloaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("ты же не разработчик")

# cogs reloader
@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 360406449685266432:
        client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("cogs is reloaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("ты же не разработчик")

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")



# words
hello_words = ['hello', 'hi', 'хай', 'привет']
answer_words = ['инфо', 'команды', 'info', 'help', 'commands']
goodbye_words = ['бб', 'пока', 'покау', 'удачи', 'адьос']

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print('я здесь!')

# Clear message
@client.command(pass_context = True)

async def clear(ctx, amount = 100):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)
    await ctx.send("Успешно очистил " + str(amount) + " сообщений.")


@client.event

async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    msg = message.content.lower()

    if msg in hello_words:
        await message.channel.send('даров,что нужно?')
    if msg in answer_words:
        await message.channel.send('команд еще нет')
    if msg in goodbye_words:
        await message.channel.send('давай пока)')

# help Message
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def help(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(tittle='Команды:')

    emb.add_field(name='{}clear'.format(PREFIX), value='очистка чата')

    await ctx.send(embed=emb)

# randomize
#тут код


# connect
token = open('TOKEN.txt', 'r').readline()

client.run(token)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```python
import os
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

PREFIX = "-"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.remove_command('help')

# cogs loader
@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 360406449685266432:
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("cogs is loaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("ты же не разработчик")

# cogs unloader
@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 360406449685266432:
        client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("cogs is unloaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("ты же не разработчик")

# cogs reloader
@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 360406449685266432:
        client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("cogs is reloaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("ты же не разработчик")

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")



# words
hello_words = ['hello', 'hi', 'хай', 'привет']
answer_words = ['инфо', 'команды', 'info', 'help', 'commands']
goodbye_words = ['бб', 'пока', 'покау', 'удачи', 'адьос']

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print('я здесь!')

# Clear message
@client.command(pass_context = True)

async def clear(ctx, amount = 100):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)
    await ctx.send("Успешно очистил " + str(amount) + " сообщений.")


@client.event

async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    msg = message.content.lower()

    if msg in hello_words:
        await message.channel.send('даров,что нужно?')
    if msg in answer_words:
        await message.channel.send('команд еще нет')
    if msg in goodbye_words:
        await message.channel.send('давай пока)')

# help Message
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def help(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(tittle='Команды:')

    emb.add_field(name='{}clear'.format(PREFIX), value='очистка чата')

    await ctx.send(embed=emb)

# randomize
@client.command()
async def randomize(ctx):
    import random
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
    msg = await ctx.send('Введите переменные:')
    args = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=60, check=check)
    args = args.content
    args = args.split('\n')
    random_choice = random.choice(args)
    await msg.delete()
    await ctx.send(f"Случайная переменная: {random_choice}")


# connect
token = open('TOKEN.txt', 'r').readline()

client.run(token)
```